# My require method does not require my php file in my second file

Tags: php

My first file 
conf.inc.php

```
<?php

$ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ip_blocked = array('127.0.0.1', '100.100.100.100');

?>
```

My second file
index.php

```
<?php
  require conf.inc.php;
  echo $ip_address;
?>
```

My require does not require the conf.inc.php files and it kills the page since it does not get the files. Can anyone help?

Comment: `require "conf.inc.php";`, file name needs to be in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Your filename should be a string. Try to use `require 'conf.inc.php';`